# Group by a calculated column and sort with swedish vocals

Tags: list, sorting, 2019, modern, group-by

Environment: SharePoint 2019 - Modern Experience - Modern List

I've created a calculated column for grouping items alphabetically but when I group by this column the group are not sorting right the swedish vocals 
(ÅÄÖ they should be at the end).

When I sort without grouping is working fine.

Anyone with same issues?

Answer (score 0):

This is the default behaviour. Even if you only sorted by the calculated column, '*Å*' and '*Ä*' would still be after '*A*' as they are treated as another variant of A.

This is due to the sites regional setting that is handling how characters are treated. (Or more likley the sort-order set for the site).

```
Site settings > Regional settings and look for "Sort order".
```

If you can't do that for any reason, you would need to add code to do the grouping differently.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! when I use sort by only there is no problem and the regional settings work fine, the problem appear when you group by a calculated column, apparently sharepoint does not apply the regional settings when grouping by a calculated column. the question is why. 

I have made a workaround but it's not the way it should work.

`=IF(LEFT(Title;1)="å";"za(å)";IF(LEFT(Title;1)="ä";"zb(ä)";IF(LEFT(Title;1)="ö";"zc(ö)";LEFT(Title;1))))`